# How to Call filters in custom phtml/Product List Page Top in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-list, filter, phtml, list.phtml

How Can I call Magento 2 default product layered navigation filters (left side filters) in top of the product list page.Can you Help me on this ?

Comment: if you can use category page as 1 column then you have display as top layer naviagtion

Comment: yes, I am using Product list page as 1 column only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just override  xml file into your theme,

```
vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/page_layout/2columns-left.xml
```

into your custom theme,

Replace xml with below code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="content" before="-"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I will check and let you know the status.

Comment: Have you checked code?

Comment: yes @Rakesh, I checked and that code is working perfectly fine for magento default theme (luma) but for my custom theme it is not working.

Comment: if possible can you suggest me how we can call that filters template file directly where ever we want.

Comment: yes, I kept it in my theme folder "Magento_Theme" module only @Rakesh But no luck :(

Comment: you have to keep xml inside app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_LayeredNavigation/page_layout/2columns-left.xml

Comment: Actually my list phtml is giving me two designs based on product type (Ex: for bundle product list view design is completely different from configurable product list view design) so actually I need to call filters only for bundle product list view.Thats why If there is a possiblity to call filters phtml only then I call that file only in bundle product type condition.

Comment: That also I tried.

Comment: You can try in your bundle xml file,keep in xml file <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="content" before="-"/>

Comment: ok, I will try in this way now and let you know :)